# Spring cloud gateway uri 413 too large when call happen

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, openfeign, spring-resttemplate

I am using microservices such as Frontend, resilience 4j api gateway and one is user microservice each service running in separate application in heroku.

When calling from frontend to api gateway service application's url, I'm getting 413 too large request exception using feign or rest template for login

Please suggest me the root cause.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap gives flexibility to programmer to write threadSafe code when they actually use it. It happened rarely that I needed a thread safe collection like ConcurrentHashMap or HashTable. What I needed is certain set of functions or certain statements in a synchronized block to be threadsafe.